# call generic method from non generic method

Tags: java, generics

I have two methods look like this. One is a generic method and the other is not.

```
<T> void a(final Class<T> type, final T instance) {
}
```

```java
void b(final Class<?> type, final Object instance) {

    if (!Objects.requireNotNull(type).isInstance(instance)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(instance + " is not an instance of " + type);
    }

    // How can I call a(type, instance)?
}
```

How can I call `a()` with `type` and `instance` from `b()`?

Comment: what about `type.isInstance(instance)`?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make `b` generic? If so, what sort of things do `a` and `b` do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a generic helper method:

```
void b(final Class<?> type, final Object instance) {

    if (!type.isInstance(instance)) {
        // throw exception
    }

    bHelper(type, instance);
}

private <T> void bHelper(final Class<T> type, final Object instance) {
    final T t = type.cast(instance);
    a(type, t);
}
```

[`Class.cast`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#cast%28java.lang.Object%29) will throw a `ClassCastException` if `instance` is not a `T` (so your earlier check may not be needed).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you! I should've been read this. [Wildcard Capture and Helper Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/capture.html)

Answer (score 0):

for example like this

```
a(String.class, new String("heloo"));
```